# How to sort a UITableView by column value in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

I have a app to show a value of bitcoin's price. I want sort when I click in the header of column.

[image]

I'am trying do this, the click has be responded, but nothing happens, the column continues not sorted.

```
struct info {
        let name: String
        let coin: String
        let change: Double
        let price: Double
    }

var ticker: Array<info> = []

@objc func tapChangeFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.ticker.sorted(by: {
            $0.change > $1.change
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you have just forgot to assign the sorted data back to the model:

```
self.ticker = self.ticker.sorted(by: {
    $0.change > $1.change
})
```

`sorted(by:)` returns a new array that is sorted, the old one is not modified, read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted):

> **Returns** the elements of the collection, sorted using the given predicate as the comparison between elements.

Or use mutating version `sort(by:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort)):

> Sorts the collection **in place**, using the given predicate as the comparison between elements.

```
self.ticker.sort(by: {
    $0.change > $1.change
})
```

Sidenote:

You don't have to dispatch `reloadData` asynchronously, you are already on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc func tapChangeFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

       self.ticker = self.ticker.sorted(by: {
            $0.change > $1.change
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Use the above function to fix the issue..
sorted method won't mutate the contents of the array ,It will return a new array instance